# Interal Hard Disk not found after installing BURG to update grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, burg

Hello I have an Alienware X51 R3 desktop computer, it orginally came with Windows 10, but I wanted it to be able to duel boot with Ubuntu 16.04.  So after successfully installing it and having the grub menu set up properly, I decided i wanted a nicer looking boot menu and found out about burg.  After following instructions to install it my computer no longer works properly.  When I turn it on it says, Internal Hard Disk Drive not found.  To do this I set my sda1 partition to have the bios_grub flag set to yes and then installed BURG on that partition.  I'm sure this is what ruined my boot partition.  I did this following this video and website https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOmL4o3JaYE, https://blog.hostonnet.com/grub-install-warning-this-gpt-partition-label-contains-no-bios-boot-partition-embedding-wont-be-possible.  Please tell me there is some way to fix this...

Comment: It would be better to tell us what process you used than to just provide a link with a youtube video.

Comment: Well I downloaded and installed the Burg packages and installed it using these commands.

Comment: 'code' sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg;
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes


sudo burg-install "(hd0)"


sudo update-burg

Finally, run the following to test and set your theme:

sudo burg-emu

Press F2 to change theme.

To revert back to GRUB enter following commands:
sudo apt-get remove --purge burg burg-themes;

sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:n-muench/burg;<br/>

sudo update-grub;'

Comment: I just started here and have no idea how to format comments..

Comment: the instructions are written in the comments of the video and are very short and clear

Comment: To add to the information, I now found out I can still boot Ubuntu in legacy mode, but not Windows 10.  In order to do this I have to hit F12 on startup and manually choose my harddrive for a legacy boot.  When I run diagnostics for my harddrive and OS Boot path there are no errors.  So I'm very confused as to what I should do.